# Remove subfolder using URL rewriting

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm not an expert of *URL rewriting* but I'd like to use *.htaccess* to show up a path like this:

`https://www.example.com/folder/login/`

in this way:

`https://www.example.com/folder/`

but I don't want a real redirect: my site should display `https://www.example.com/folder/login/` page, but the URL would be different, so that an user could think that he still is on `https://www.example.com/folder/` while logging in.

Is it possible?

If it is, one last question: I have already enabled `RewriteEngine on` on the ROOT folder, do I have to put it in another *.htaccess* file too (which is places into `https://www.example.com/folder/login/`)?

Comment: What is the file that actually handles the request? This is the file that you should rewrite to. Presumably you are already linking to `/folder/` and not `/folder/login/`?

Comment: I want to show up `/folder/login/` but with the URL `/folder/`

Answer (score 0):

`/folder/` is the requested URL and what appears in the browser's address bar and `/folder/login/` is the underlying filesystem path that the request is rewritten to.

To internally rewrite `/folder/` to `/folder/login/` try the following in the root `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder/$ /folder/login/ [L]
```

`/folder/login/` is presumably a filesystem directory, so this won't directly handle the request. Ideally, you would rewrite directly to the file that handles the request. In this case, I assume mod_dir will issue an internal subrequest for the directory index document, eg. `index.php`?

> I have already enabled RewriteEngine on on the ROOT folder

Note that the order of directives matters.

> do I have to put it in another `.htaccess` file too (which is places into `https://www.example.com/folder/login/`)

No, you can put it in the root `.htaccess` file. (You could put it in `/folder/.htaccess`, but the directives would need to change. It wouldn't make sense to put it in `/folder/login/.htaccess` since you then couldn't hide the `/login` subdirectory.)

Comment: The problem is that there is another file into `/folder/`, so redirecting it I think it would create a conflict, wouldn't it?

Comment: You can't have two different responses from the same URL. Either `/folder/` returns "another file" _or_ it returns the contents from `/folder/login/` - you can't do both. If a user requests `/folder/`, how does your server know which content to respond with?

Comment: I thought it was possible to have `folder` on its own path (so that you can request `folder` and open it) and when you request `folder/login` it does open `folder/login`, but you only *visualize* `/folder/` on the address bar

Comment: No, you can't do that - not with `.htaccess`. When you request `/folder/login/` then that is what you see in the browser's address bar. You could externally redirect the request back to `/folder/` so `/folder/login/` effectively "disappears" from the address bar (the user won't necessarily see it in the address bar as it's v.quick), but the user will have seen `/folder/login/` in the _status bar_ and in the link on the page. But now you have the problem of one URL `/folder/` which is expected to show 2 different pages. The URL needs to be unique.

Comment: Thank you... so I think I will rewrite to another URL. Where do I have to put .htaccess? it doesn't work on the root folder

Comment: Having too many `.htaccess` files in different folders can be hard to maintain. You probably only need one `.htaccess` file in the document root, but note that the order of the directives are important. If you have a `.htaccess` file in `/path/to/dir/` then it is only processed when `/path/to/dir/` is requested (either directly or via an internal rewrite).